# PhotoKit: get full resolution offline asset preview, when the requested asset is in iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

When loading images from the photo library via PhotoKit, it can happen that the image is not downloaded from iCloud. In this case, a low-resolution "placeholder" version of that image is available locally if you browse it in the photos App:

[image]

However, when I try to get the same photo to display in an app, the photo that I get from `PHAssetManager` will be at maximum `120` units wide (or high). This looks very blurry and is completely unusable except for a thumbnail.

[image: Blurry image in app]

I have already tried

- `PHImageManagerMaximumSize` as the target size
- `resizeMode = .none` and `.exact`
- all the `deliveryMode`'s
- `requestImageDataAndOrientation`
- to read the image data in a different way, e.g. by `privateFileURL` property on the asset

I wanted to ask if anyone has come across this issue and maybe worked around it.

The behavior can be easily reproduced with some PhotoKit example app, for example from [these course materials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/11764166-getting-started-with-photokit).
This is the code I used to produce the below image:

```
extension UIImageView {
  func fetchImageAsset(_ asset: PHAsset?, targetSize size: CGSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode = .aspectFill, completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {

    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
    options.resizeMode = .none
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = false

    // 1
    guard let asset = asset else {
      completionHandler?(false)
      return
    }
    // 2
    let resultHandler: (UIImage?, [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Void = { image, info in
      if let image = image {
        self.image = image
      }
      completionHandler?(true)
    }
    // 3
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(
      for: asset,
      targetSize: size,
      contentMode: contentMode,
      options: options,
      resultHandler: resultHandler)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter-intuitively, PHImageManager will return higher-resolution images when the requested target size is *below* a certain threshold.

This gives us an ugly albeit functioning workaround that can be implemented as follows.

First, load the image as usual.

If the loading is completed (`PHImageResultIsDegradedKey` is `0`) but `PHImageResultIsInCloudKey` is `1`, load the image again with the `targetSize` `360x360`, which I have found a suitable value by experimentation. Here it is important to use the `opportunistic` delivery mode and `.none` for the `resizeMode`. Other values for these settings do not work.

Here is an excerpt of my code. The `continuation.yield` calls carry information about the process to the outside, `async` world.

```
func imageRequestOptions(deliveryMode: PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode,
                         progressHandler: PHAssetImageProgressHandler? = nil) -> PHImageRequestOptions {
    let opts = PHImageRequestOptions()
    opts.resizeMode = .none
    opts.isSynchronous = false
    opts.isNetworkAccessAllowed = networkAccessAllowed()
    opts.deliveryMode = deliveryMode
    opts.progressHandler = progressHandler
    return opts
}
...
let targetSizeForOfflinePhotos = CGSize(width: 360, height: 360)
if metadata?[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] as? Int == 0
    && metadata?[PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] as? Int == 1  {
    continuation.yield(.internetAccessRequired)
    let requestId = assetManager
        .requestImage(
            for: asset,
            targetSize: targetSizeForOfflinePhotos,
            contentMode: .aspectFill,
            options:
                imageRequestOptions(
                    deliveryMode: .opportunistic
                )
        ) { image, metadata in
            if let image = image {
                continuation.yield(.imageAvailable(.uiImage(image)))
            } else {
                continuation.finish(throwing: PhotoLibraryError.assetNotFound)
            }
        }
    continuation.onTermination = { _ in
        Task {
            assetManager.cancelImageRequest(requestId)
        }
    }
```

There might still be a correct way to implement image loading for offline scenarios. Unfortunately as of now, this hack is the only thing that I can find and it improves user experience by a vast margin in my case.

It seems that I am also not the only one having trouble with this: I downloaded multiple popular apps that deal with library photos, and they all suffer from the same issue I described in the question.